# php - How do I loop through variable-names (in a function) while making them global

Tags: php, for-loop, global-variables

I hope someone can help.
I have a for-loop in a function:

```
for ($i = $o; $i <= $l; $i++){     ...     }
```

In which I create new variables while looping:

```
${'var' . $i} = ...
```

I want to make these variables global, `$GLOBALS['...'] = ...`-style, but `$GLOBALS["{'var' . $i}"]` doesn't seem to work... is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the inside with quotes? Have you tried `$GLOBALS[{'var' . $i}]`?

Comment: Because the "make global"-command is defined as $GLOBALS['...']... Your suggestion wouldn't work syntactically

Comment: I just tested with this code: `$GLOBALS['var'.$i] = $i;` and it worked.

Comment: FWIW: this is wrong on so many levels…

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seemed to work:

```
<?php

     $GLOBALS['test'] = "brick";

     echo $GLOBALS['test'];

     for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
         $GLOBALS['var'.$i] = $i;
     }

     print_r($GLOBALS);

?>
```

Output: `[GLOBALS] => Array *RECURSION* [i] => 6 [test] => brick [var0] => 0 [var1] => 1 [var2] => 2 [var3] => 3 [var4] => 4 [var5] => 5 )` (After all the spam of the rest of `$GLOBALS`)

Your problem is basically that you are including doublequotes inside the selector part of the variable, which is not needed.